# how to show an alert inside a modal

Tags: angular, typescript

i would like to know how can i show an alert inside a modal. shown in the below posted code is my attempt to achieve that, but the result i am getting is as shown in the below posted screen-shot.
please let me know how to show an alert inside a modal

**code**:

```
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="openAWANTIVer2WSExceptionGUI" [clrModalClosable]=true [clrModalStaticBackdrop]=true>
 
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog fadeDown in" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-content">
               
                <div id="al" class="alert alert-success alert-sm" role="alert">sadfs dsfdsfasf </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</clr-modal>
```

**img**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to hide/show the alert box, this example shows using jquery when whenever the condition matches it will show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#alertbox').click(function(){
    $("#error").html("You Clicked on Click here Button");
      $('#myModal').modal("show");
    });
  });
```